# Linux desktop environments with window and top bar integration

Tags: linux, open-source, desktop-environment

I really like Ubuntu Unity top panel integration with the windows (maximized ones) because it saves space. See the screenshot:

> [image: Ubuntu with Unity: top panel shows title of the maximized program]

What other Linux desktop environments have this feature? This is the thing that makes me use Unity.

They should have the following features:

- be simple
- look good (maybe better than Unity, I know it's subjective, but everyone should know what looks good and what not)
- be customisable
- be fast
- run in parallel with Unity
- open source

Comment: Please tell us what you do not like in Unity, and what you expect in a desktop environment.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I love Unity, but I would like to know if there are other desktop environments with this feature. Maybe I find something better than Unity. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this QA site does not consider as on-topic questions like "Give me all equivalents of X"... please add one requirement that Unity does not have, and your question will be on-topic :-) Are you really perfectly happy with Unity, absolutely nothing to improve? Think hard!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine most distributions support this feature by default or with some tinkering using plugins.

[Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com) has this functionality natively.

Just `Right-Click` panel -> `Edit Panel` and change the `Layout` to Top.

After this change my Desktop looked like this:

[image]

And with a maximized window opened:

[image]

Comment: That's the thing: the maximized window is not integrated with the top panel. Please compare with my screenshot (Unity) to understand what I mean.

Comment: Oh you mean the title of the window. Well... okay I respect that, I'll search a bit after work if it's possible to remove it in Cinnamon and if not I'll delete my answer.

Comment: The title, the buttons, the menu. If you can find more desktops, just add more answers. :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds pretty much like you may want Gnome3 as your desktop environment. It's quite similar to Unity, but a lot more customisable.

[image]

It gives an integrated top bar like Unity, with the menu options. There's also plenty of addons available at https://extensions.gnome.org/ to customise it too.

There's an extension to 'force' undecorated windows too, which sounds like what you may be after: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/354/maximus/

If you're using Fedora or Arch, or any of the more 'bleeding edge' distros, you may need to do a little hack to get the extension working:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/maximus-gnome-shell-extension

nano maximus-gnome-shell-extension/maximus@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/metadata.json

"shell-version": [
     "3.4",
     "3.6",
     "3.8",
     "3.9",
     "3.10",
     "3.12",
     "3.13
 ],

cp -r maximus-gnome-shell-extension/maximus@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/maximus@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/schemas/
```

Then log out and log back in again. The extension can be configured by gnome-tweak-tool (which you may need to install, it's in the official repositories).

Answer (score 0):

KDE can have a top bar configured to behave like Unity, using software from https://github.com/psifidotos.

Using latte-dock as the top bar, applet-window-appmenu for the Global Menu and applet-window-buttons for the window controls, and this tip https://medium.com/@CodyReichert/how-to-hide-title-bars-in-kde-plasma-5-348e0df4087f to hide the title bars of maximized windows.

You can also maximize windows by double-clicking empty space in the top bar, and drag windows (including maximized ones) from the top bar.

As a bonus, you can have a Unity-like HUD by installing plasma-hud. You can then move the bottom bar to the side for a close match to Unity.

Unfortunately psifidotos' software is no longer being maintained so may stop working at any time due to changes in KDE Plasma.